# Did Lord Krishna move around with four arms or two arms?

Tags: vishnu, krishna

Lord Krishna who is avatara of Lord Vishnu is said have to revealed his chaturbhuja form to many during his avatara. Who are the those to whom Lord Krishna revealed his divine chaturbhuja form ?

Moreover are their any instances quoted by any acharyas how Lord Krishna moved around i.e In his chaturbhuja form or two armed form?

Please quote verses from scriptures or refer to the specific verse number from genuine scriptures?

Please dont indulge in tangential discussions like which form is superior etc

Answer (score 5):

According to [Srimad Bhagavatam](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/3/9-10/), Vasudeva saw Lord Krishna with four hands just after His birth.

> tam adbhutaṁ bālakam ambujekṣaṇaṁ
>   **catur-bhujaṁ
>   śaṅkha-gadādy-udāyudham**
>  śrīvatsa-lakṣmaṁ gala-śobhi-kaustubhaṁ
>    pītāmbaraṁ sāndra-payoda-saubhagam
>
> mahārha-vaidūrya-kirīṭa-kuṇḍala-
>   tviṣā
>   pariṣvakta-sahasra-kuntalam
>  uddāma-kāñcy-aṅgada-kaṅkaṇādibhir
>    virocamānaṁ vasudeva aikṣata
>
> Vasudeva then saw the newborn child, who had very wonderful lotuslike
>   eyes and **who bore in His four hands the four weapons śaṅkha, cakra,
>   gadā and padma**. On His chest was the mark of Śrīvatsa and on His neck
>   the brilliant Kaustubha gem. Dressed in yellow, His body blackish like
>   a dense cloud, His scattered hair fully grown, and His helmet and
>   earrings sparkling uncommonly with the valuable gem Vaidūrya, the
>   child, decorated with a brilliant belt, armlets, bangles and other
>   ornaments, appeared very wonderful.

But [Harivamsa Parva](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_004.html) of Mahabharata doesn't mention explicitly His Chaturbhuja form at the time of birth. It mentions just Srivatsa and some divine signs.

> vasudevashcha taM rAtrau jAtaM putramadhokShajam ||2-4-21 
>   **shrIvatsalakShaNaM dR^iShTvA yutaM divyaishcha lakShaNaiH** |
>
> Vasudeva saw his son, adhokShaja (kR^iShNa), **who was born that night.
>   He saw the divine signs and marks such as shrIvatsa**
>
> uvAcha vasudevastu rUpaM saMhara vai prabho ||2-4-22
>  bhIto.aham
>   deva kaMsasya tasmAdevaM bravImyaham | 
>  mama putrA hatAstena tava
>   jyeShThAmbujekShaNa ||2-4-23
>
> vasudeva said: Lord, please withdraw your form. I am terrified of
>   kaMsa. Hence I am saying this. O lord with lotus eyes! My sons, your
>   elder brothers, were killed by kaMsa.
>
> vaishampAyana uvAcha
>  vasudevavachaH shrutvA rUpaM chAharadachyutaH
>   | 
>  anuj~nApya pitR^itvena nanda gopagR^ihaM naya ||2-4-24
>
> vaishampAyana said:
>  Hearing the words of vasudeva, achyuta
>   (viShNu) concealed his form. He persuaded his father to take him to
>   the house of nandagopa.

Comment: Your answer only answers the question  partially.  What are Other instances where he revealed his chaturbhuja form and any references by any acharyas on how he moved around?

Comment: @Krishna Sorry. I know only this instance.  I heard discourse of a Acharya and he said that Lord Krishna was born with four hands and i searched the verse.

Comment: No worries. You have answered  one major point that Lord Krishna was born with chaturbhuja as per Srimad Bhagavatham. Thanks

Comment: I think the verse in Srimad Bhagavatam is interpolation, taking birth with four hands is completely ridiculous.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria why ridiculous? He is 100% Vishnu. Swami Vivekanda said that we can we see Vishnu with 4 hands when we realize or when we advance in Yoga. That was Dwapara Yuga and it could be possible.

Comment: @TheDestroyer There have been many avatars like Krishna, he is not unique. Swami Sivananda also said when we advance spiritually, we will see Vishnu with 4 hands but not a new born baby with 4 hands.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Iswara or Avatar can born at His own will in any form. He has power to materialize in any form. So, new born Krishna could have  four hands. This is possible. In Tamil version, Skanda or Kartikeya was born with 6 heads, though i'm not sure whether Skanda has physical body or not..

Comment: @Chimay yes. Even I'm personally not sure whether Devi Bhagavatam or Krishna Bhagavatam is authentic. Yes. Srimad Bagavatam exaggerates and Isckon's commentary makes this exaggeration  worse. But my point is about 4 armed form which could be possible. But not sure personally whether Vishnu incarnated as such.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think the "divine signs" probably included having four arms.

Comment: @Keshav not sure. Could be.

Comment: @Keshav - I agree with you, that chaturbhuja aa one of the main divine signs along with host of other divine signs as Srivatsa etc. In fact, in the Vishwaroopa darshan of Bhagavad Gita, Arjuna requests and pleads Krishna to show him the most auspicious Chaturbhuja form and Krishna accepts his request.

Answer (score 3):

Vishnu Purana(4.11.4) says:

> यदोर्वंशं नरः श्रुत्वा सर्वपापैः प्रमुच्यते । यत्रावतीर्णं
> **कृष्णाख्यंपरं ब्रह्मनराकृति** ||
>
> yador vaṁśaṁ naraḥ śrutvā sarva-pāpaiḥ pramucyate | yatrāvatīrṇaṁ
> **kṛṣṇākhyaṁ paraṁ brahma narākṛt**i ||
>
> Hearing of the dynasty of Yadu, one becomes free of all sins. In that
> dynasty appeared **Kṛṣṇa, the supreme Brahman in human form**.

Bhagavata Purana(7.15.75) says:

> यूयं नृलोके बत भूरिभागा लोकं पुनाना मुनयोऽभियन्ति येषां गृहानावसतीति
> साक्षाद्गूढं **परं ब्रह्म मनुष्यलिङ्गम्**
>
> yūyaṁ nṛ-loke bata bhūri-bhāgā lokaṁ punānā munayo ’bhiyanti yeṣāṁ
> gṛhān āvasatīti sākṣād gūḍhaṁ **paraṁ brahma manuṣya-liṅgam**
>
> You Pāṇḍavas are most fortunate in this world. Sages who purify the
> planets come to your houses because **the Supreme Brahman personally
> resides in your houses in a human form**.

Arjuna requests Krishna to show four handed form:

> tenaiva rūpeṇa catur-bhujena sahasra-bāho bhava viśva-mūrte ||
>
> O thousand-armed one, form of the universe! Appear with that
> four-armed form. BG 11.46

After showing four handed form, Krishna takes his two handed form again.

> dṛṣṭvedaṁ mānuṣaṁ rūpaṁ tava saumyaṁ janārdana | idānīm asmi saṁvṛttaḥ
> sa-cetāḥ prakṛtiṁ gataḥ ||
>
> O Janārdana, seeing your pleasant human form, my mind has become
> peaceful and I have gained composure. BG 11.51

Vishnu Sahasranama of Padma Purana(6.71.249) says:

> **नराकृतिः परंब्रह्म narākrṭi param brahma**
>
> [Kṛṣṇa is] **the supreme
> Brahman in human form**.

**From all these, we can conclude that Krishna moved around in 2 handed form**.

At few places, he showed four handed forms.

While taking birth, Krishna appeared in four handed form:

Bhagavata Purana(10.3.9-10) says:

> tam adbhutaṁ bālakam ambujekṣaṇaṁ **catur-bhujaṁ śaṅkha-gadāry-udāyudham**
> | śrīvatsa-lakṣmaṁ gala-śobhi-kaustubhaṁ pītāmbaraṁ
> sāndra-payoda-saubhagam || mahārha-vaidūrya-kirīṭa-kuṇḍalatviṣā
> pariṣvakta-sahasra-kuntalam | uddāma-kāñcy-aṅgada-kaṅkaṇādibhir
> virocamānaṁ vasudeva aikṣata ||
>
> Vasudeva saw an amazing boy: His eyes resembled two lotuses. **His four
> arms held eminent weapons: the conch, the mace and the cakr**a. He had
> the mark of Śrīvatsa. On His neck, the Kaustubha was dazzling. His
> garments were yellow. His splendor was more charming than the hue of
> rain clouds. His immeasurable head hair mingled with the effulgence of
> His two earrings and of His crown, which was studded with the highly
> valuable Vaidūrya gem. And He was especially resplendent with His
> magnificent girdle, armlets, and forearm ornaments.

The reason why Krishna appeared in 4 handed form instead of 2 handed form directly is explained in the same chapter later.

Bhagavata Purana(10.3.44) says:

> etad vāṁ darśitaṁ rūpaṁ prāg-janma-smaraṇāya me | nānyathā mad-bhavaṁ
> jñānaṁ martya-liṅgena jāyate ||
>
> This form is shown to both of you for the sake of reminding you about
> My past lives, otherwise knowledge of Me does not occur, because I
> have a characteristic of mortals.[The sense is: because I am Para-Brahman in a
> human shape.]

Another instance where Krishna manifested four arms:

Bhagavata Purana(10.60.26) says:

> paryaṅkād avaruhyāśu  tām utthāpya **catur-bhujaḥ** keśān samuhya
> tad-vaktraṁ  prāmṛjat padma-pāṇinā
>
> The Lord quickly got down from the bed. **Manifesting four arms**, He
> picked her up, gathered her hair and caressed her face with His lotus
> hand.

Vishwanath Chakravarty Thakur comments that Lord manifested four arms to do these activities simultaneously.

Another instance where Krishna manifested four hands:

Bhagavata Purana(1.7.52) says:

> niśamya bhīma-gaditaṁ  draupadyāś ca **catur-bhujaḥ** ālokya vadanaṁ
> sakhyur  idam āha hasann iva
>
> Hearing the words of Bhima and Draupadi, **Krsna with four hands** looked
> towards his friend Arjuna while smiling and spoke.

The reason why Krishna manifested 4 arms here is explained by Sridhara Svami and Vishwanath Chakravarty as follows.

Bhima favored killing Asvatthama and Draupadi favored releasing him. The
Lord assumed four arms to keep the two parties apart.

.